# What can go when resetting mysql password?

Tags: mysql, passwords, reset

I was resetting my password for mysql. I was following the guidelines below.
I am now getting the error "ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)".

```bash
sudo service mysql stop
sudo mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables --skip-syslog --skip-networking
mysql -u root
UPDATE mysql.user SET Password=PASSWORD('password') WHERE User='root';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
Exit
```

Any recommendations to fix it.Thanks.
I'm on a Debian OS

Comment: Where are you getting the error? Have you tried from command line?

Comment: when i type in mysql on the command line get the error 'ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
' it also seems i have no mysqld directory  in /var/run

Comment: To connect to mysql using a password, you should use the `-p` option as well...